# fetching the data from the database

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

```
Emp.java

    package com.javatpoint;  

    public class Emp {  
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary;  
    private String designation;  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  
    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  
    public float getSalary() {  
        return salary;  
    }  
    public void setSalary(float salary) {  
        this.salary = salary;  
    }  
    public String getDesignation() {  
        return designation;  
    }  
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {  
        this.designation = designation;  
    }  

    } 


EmpController.java


    package com.javatpoint;  
    import java.util.ArrayList;  
    import java.util.List;  
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  
    import com.javatpoint.Emp;  
    import com.javatpoint.EmpDao;  
    @Controller  
    public class EmpController {  
        @Autowired  
        EmpDao dao;//will inject dao from xml file  

        /*It displays a form to input data, here "command" is a reserved request attribute 
         *which is used to display object data into form 
         */  
        @RequestMapping("/empform")  
        public ModelAndView showform(){  
            return new ModelAndView("empform","command",new Emp());  
        }  
        /*It saves object into database. The @ModelAttribute puts request data 
         *  into model object. You need to mention RequestMethod.POST method  
         *  because default request is GET*/  
        @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
        public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("emp") Emp emp){  
            dao.save(emp);  
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/empform.jsp");//will redirect to viewemp request mapping  
        }  
        /* It provides list of employees in model object */  
        @RequestMapping("/viewemp")  
        public ModelAndView viewemp(){  
            List<Emp> list=dao.getEmployees();  
            return new ModelAndView("viewemp","list",list);  
        }  


    }

EmpDao.java

    package com.javatpoint;  
    import java.sql.ResultSet;  
    import java.sql.SQLException;  
    import java.util.List;  
    import

 org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;  
import com.javatpoint.Emp;  

public class EmpDao {  
JdbcTemplate template;  

public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}  
public int save(Emp p){  
    String sql="insert into emp(name,salary,designation) values('"+p.getName()+"',"+p.getSalary()+",'"+p.getDesignation()+"')";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  

public Emp getEmpById(int id){  
    String sql="select * from emp where name=?";  
    return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Emp>(Emp.class));  
}  
public List<Emp> getEmployees(){  
    return template.query("select * from emp",new RowMapper<Emp>(){  
        public Emp mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {  
            Emp e=new Emp();  

            e.setName(rs.getString(1));  
            e.setSalary(rs.getFloat(2));  
            e.setDesignation(rs.getString(3));  
            return e;  
        }  
    });  
}  

}



spring1-servlet.xml




     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">    

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint"/>  


        <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/headway" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="toor" />
            </bean>

        <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="dao" class="com.javatpoint.EmpDao">  
        <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>  
        </bean>  
          </beans>


 web.xml


<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

empform.jsp


    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Add New Employee</h1>  
           <form method="post" action="save">    
            <table >    
             <tr>    
              <td>Name : </td>   
              <td><input path="name"  /></td>  
             </tr>    
             <tr>    
              <td>Salary :</td>    
              <td><input path="salary" /></td>  
             </tr>   
             <tr>    
              <td>Designation :</td>    
              <td><input path="designation" /></td>  
             </tr>   
             <tr>    
              <td> </td>    
              <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>    
             </tr>    
            </table>    
           <form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

viewemp.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Employees List</h1>  
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th><th>Designation</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  
   <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">   
   <tr>  
   <td>${emp.id}</td>  
   <td>${emp.name}</td>  
   <td>${emp.salary}</td>  
   <td>${emp.designation}</td>  
   <td><a href="editemp/${emp.id}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.id}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>  
   </table>  
   <br/>  
   <a href="empform.jsp">Add New Employee</a>  
</body>
</html>




    hi
```

I am trying to fetching the data from the database but it show's  the only curd .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxBcH.png) it show the like that .

and it display the jsp file data. I am check the all possible way to display the data from the database.curd will be displayed but it show's the jsp file data.

please check the my code and provide the solution.

```
    thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this solution is gonna work in you case,
but i think you forget to add JSTL Core Tags

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

after this jstl know `<c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">` will render as for loop and in each iteration `emp` is your object variable